# Jackrabbit index boost configuration

Tags: lucene, aem, jackrabbit

I'm trying to understand the use of 'boosting' properties in the indexing configuration for CQ5. I thought I understood from http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/IndexingConfiguration that setting a boost determined how far up the list an item would be returned as a search result. So I tried adding the following boost lines to my default CQ5 indexing configuration:

```
<index-rule nodeType="nt:base">
<property boost="5.0">jcr:title</property>
<property boost="5.0">history:title</property>
<property boost="3.0">history:description</property>
<property boost="3.0">history:caption</property>
<property boost="2.0">text</property>
<property nodeScopeIndex="false">analyticsProvider</property>
<property nodeScopeIndex="false">analyticsSnippet</property>
<property nodeScopeIndex="false">hideInNav</property>
<property nodeScopeIndex="false">offTime</property>
<property nodeScopeIndex="false">onTime</property>
  :
  :
<property isRegexp="true">.*:.*</property>
</index-rule>
```

The intent was that, in a full text search, text found in jcr:title or history:title properties would be the most relevant followed by history:description, history:caption and, finally, text. 
I deleted the index information from the repository and from the workspace, then restarted CQ and let it rebuild all of the indexes.
Now when I do a full text search, I'm only getting results if the search text is in the nodename itself - nothing from description, caption, etc.

Obviously I've done something wrong but I'm not sure what. Any help would be greatly appreciated.